# Set img src property from byte[]

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, base64

I'm trying to show the thumbnailPhoto property of an ActiveDirectory user on an MVC View. 
I'm parsing the needed properties to a List of a class named Employee:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
            {
                result = resultCol[counter];

                if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") &&
                    result.Properties.Contains("displayname") &&
                    result.Properties.Contains("sn") &&
                    result.Properties.Contains("givenName"))
                {
                    list.Add(new Employee
                    {
                        Email = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0],
                        FirstName = (String)result.Properties["givenName"][0],
                        LastName = (String)result.Properties["sn"][0],
                        pictureBLOB = result.Properties.Contains("thumbnailPhoto") ? (byte[])result.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] : null,
                    });
                }
            }
```

I did some research on how to display the picture on the Index View and found this as a possible solution:

```
<div class="container">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    String imgSrc = String.Empty;
    String base64 = String.Empty;

    if (item.pictureBLOB != null)
    {
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.pictureBLOB);
        imgSrc = String.Format("data:image;base64,{0}", base64);

    }

    <div id="@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Number)" class="col col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a class="post" mailto="@item.Email" href="#">
            <img src="{@imgSrc}" title="@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.LastName), @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.FirstName)" />
            @*onerror="this.src = '../../Content/Images/nopicture.gif';" />*@
        </a>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

But when I call the index page, the pictures won't be shown. Is there any other possibility to show the profile pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I simply had to remove the braces around @imgSrc in

```
  <img src="{@imgSrc}" title="@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.LastName), @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.FirstName)" />
```